# Constantly update Datetime variable in C# console application

Tags: c#, datetime, console

I am trying to run a piece of code on user defined time but the datetime variable stores the value of time when i hit run and does not update to check if the time has changed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("please enter the date in m/d/y h/m/s am/pm     format ");
          DateTime bombDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
          repeat:
          //DateTime bombDate = "7/27/2016 4:13:16 AM";

          DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
              if (bombDate == now)
              {
                  string _str = " this is a virus, you have been hit by a logic bomb  ...";
                  while (true)
                  {
                      foreach (char c in _str)
                      {
                          SendKeys.SendWait(c.ToString());
                          Thread.Sleep(200);


                      }
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                  }

              }

              else {
                  goto repeat;
              }
```

Comment: Do you mean `now` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match the two dates exactly, you're comparing the ticks here and the chances the two dates execute exactly at the same time `Now` matches the date is not that high. Since you're only specifying seconds from input then use this:

```
if ((bombDate - now).TotalSeconds < 0)
```

This matches the two dates even if there is it passed by up to less that 1 second.

Or you can just check if the needed time has passed:

```
if ((bombDate <= now))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment but I can't.

Depending on what you're trying to do it might be worth to consider to write the program and just use a standard facility like the windows task scheduler to actually run it on specific conditions/times.

In addition goto is frowned up on by a lot of people for a good reason. Essentially you're creating a loop. Why not declare it as such? One possibility would be to use a loop which just counts the time (which is essentially what you're doing in your outer loop).

```
DateTime now = NULL;
while(bombDate != now){
    now = DateTime.Now;
}
// Other Code beginning with string _str =
```

On way to circumvent the timing problem would be to add another sleep after your initial assignment/before the loop. That way you would be sure that some time passed between the successive calls of DateTime.Now. Going for a finer resolution like user3185569 suggested might be better though.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice on "goto" i'll keep that in mind.